# Sections of the restriction of a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there a simple relation between the (global) sections of a line bundle and the (global) sections of its restriction to some subvariety?

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $j\colon C\hookrightarrow X$ some smooth irreducible (codimension 1) subvariety. What is the relation between

$H^0(C,j^\ast\mathcal{O}(D))$ and $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(D))$,

where $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is some line bundle on $X$ ? (I am considering $\dim X=2$ but I guess this is general)

Comment: @L_b I guess what you mean is the sequence $0\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X(D)\to\mathcal{O}_D(D)\to 0$ but I am not sure how to use it to study $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for a typo. If I am not mistaken, the last sheaf is precisely the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)$ to $D$, that is, $j^{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)$. I hope that now it is correct...

Comment: @L_b's suggestion is not correct because $j^*\mathcal O_X(D)$ is a sheaf on $C$ whereas the other two sheaves $\mathcal O_X \operatorname {and} \mathcal O_X(D)$ are sheaves on $X$. In an exact sequence of sheaves all sheaves must live on the same space.

Comment: On the other hand it seems as if everyone leaves out the $j_*$ just the same.

Comment: There's certainly a map $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))\to H^0(C,j^*\mathcal{O}_X(D))$ by restricting sections. I don't think it's injective nor surjective in general.